# Unable to import Keras Library

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on Artificial Neural Network Algorithm on a dataset. Below is the source of dataset I am using.

[Kaggle Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/hj5992/churn-modelling/data)

I have ran the code until Feature Scaling and it ran successfully without any issues. Below is the code which I ran :-

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:\Machine learning\practices\Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder\Part 8 - Deep Learning\Section 39 - Artificial Neural Networks (ANN)\Artificial-Neural-Networks\Artificial_Neural_Networks\Churn1_Modelling.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

After this I ran

```
import keras
```

It gave me the error as Python stopped working and Kernel got restarted every time. I have installed all the libraries and modules. Below are the modules which I already installed :-

```
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -----------
alabaster                          0.7.9
anaconda-clean                     1.0
anaconda-client                    1.5.1
anaconda-navigator                 1.3.1
argcomplete                        1.0.0
astroid                            1.4.7
astropy                            1.2.1
Babel                              2.3.4
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.weakref                  1.0rc1
beautifulsoup4                     4.5.1
bitarray                           0.8.1
blaze                              0.10.1
bleach                             1.5.0
bokeh                              0.12.2
boto                               2.42.0
Bottleneck                         1.1.0
certifi                            2018.8.24
cffi                               1.7.0
chardet                            3.0.4
chest                              0.2.3
click                              6.6
cloudpickle                        0.2.1
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.3.7
comtypes                           1.1.2
conda                              4.5.11
conda-build                        2.0.2
configobj                          5.0.6
contextlib2                        0.5.3
cryptography                       1.5
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.24.1
cytoolz                            0.9.0.1
dask                               0.11.0
datashape                          0.5.2
decorator                          4.0.10
dill                               0.2.5
docutils                           0.12
dynd                               c328ab7
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.0.2
filelock                           2.0.6
Flask                              0.11.1
Flask-Cors                         2.1.2
gevent                             1.1.2
greenlet                           0.4.10
h5py                               2.6.0
HeapDict                           1.0.0
html5lib                           0.9999999
idna                               2.1
imagesize                          0.7.1
ipykernel                          4.5.0
ipython                            5.1.0
ipython-genutils                   0.1.0
ipywidgets                         5.2.2
itsdangerous                       0.24
jdcal                              1.2
jedi                               0.9.0
Jinja2                             2.8
jsonschema                         2.5.1
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     4.4.0
jupyter-console                    5.0.0
jupyter-core                       4.2.0
Keras                              2.2.2
Keras-Applications                 1.0.4
Keras-Preprocessing                1.0.2
keyring                            13.2.1
lazy-object-proxy                  1.2.1
llvmlite                           0.13.0
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               3.6.4
Markdown                           2.2.0
MarkupSafe                         0.23
matplotlib                         1.5.3
menuinst                           1.4.1
mistune                            0.7.3
mkl-fft                            1.0.4
mkl-random                         1.0.1
mpmath                             0.19
multipledispatch                   0.4.8
nb-anacondacloud                   1.2.0
nb-conda                           2.0.0
nb-conda-kernels                   2.0.0
nbconvert                          4.2.0
nbformat                           4.1.0
nbpresent                          3.0.2
networkx                           1.11
nltk                               3.2.1
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           4.2.3
numba                              0.28.1
numexpr                            2.6.7
numpy                              1.15.1
numpydoc                           0.8.0
odo                                0.5.0
olefile                            0.45.1
openpyxl                           2.3.2
pandas                             0.18.1
partd                              0.3.6
path.py                            0.0.0
pathlib2                           2.1.0
patsy                              0.4.1
pep8                               1.7.0
pickleshare                        0.7.4
Pillow                             5.2.0
pip                                18.0
pkginfo                            1.3.2
ply                                3.9
prompt-toolkit                     1.0.3
protobuf                           3.6.1
psutil                             4.3.1
py                                 1.4.31
pyasn1                             0.1.9
pycodestyle                        2.4.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.14
pycrypto                           2.6.1
pycurl                             7.43.0.2
pyflakes                           1.3.0
Pygments                           2.2.0
pylint                             1.5.4
pyOpenSSL                          16.2.0
pyparsing                          2.1.4
pytest                             2.9.2
python-dateutil                    2.5.3
pytz                               2016.6.1
pywin32                            220
PyYAML                             3.12
pyzmq                              15.4.0
QtAwesome                          0.4.4
qtconsole                          4.2.1
QtPy                               1.5.0
requests                           2.14.2
rope-py3k                          0.9.4.post1
ruamel-yaml                        -VERSION
scikit-image                       0.12.3
scikit-learn                       0.19.2
scipy                              1.1.0
setuptools                         40.2.0
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.11.0
snowballstemmer                    1.2.1
sockjs-tornado                     1.0.3
sphinx                             1.4.6
spyder                             3.3.1
spyder-kernels                     0.2.4
SQLAlchemy                         1.0.13
statsmodels                        0.6.1
sympy                              1.0
tables                             3.2.2
tensorflow                         1.2.0
Theano                             1.0.2
toolz                              0.8.0
tornado                            4.4.1
traitlets                          4.3.0
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
wcwidth                            0.1.7
Werkzeug                           0.14.1
wheel                              0.31.1
widgetsnbextension                 1.2.6
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.10.6
xlrd                               1.0.0
XlsxWriter                         0.9.3
xlwings                            0.10.0
xlwt                               1.1.2
```

Please let me know if something is wrong with installing the tensorflow and keras or if there is something else which went wrong as I am not able to go ahead with the use Artificial Neural Network algorithm to predict the values.

Thank you.

Comment: what error message do you get ?

Comment: Which package mangers are you using?  e.g. pip, conda, ...  Do you have multiple environments? Also, it looks like you might be using Jupyter notebook.   You might trying running in just vanilla python (or ipython).

Comment: Hi @rocksportrocker, I am getting error like python stopped working and kernel in spyder got restarted every time. Let me if I can upload the screen shot for the same in this comment below?

Comment: Hi @ShpielMeister I am using pip in python console and I am using spyder notebook for all the codes.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are doing SuperDataScience machine learning az course.
You code is right and you are doing well. If you are using anaconda kernel(spyder IDE use anaconda kernel), try to install tensorflow by `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`.
 based on the library list you provided, you have installed tensorflow by conda forge.
After installing tensorflow by `pip`, try to test your tensorflow installation by

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))
```

you should see this output `Hello, TensorFlow!`
Now you can try to check your `keras` installation by running this code `pip install keras`
And `import keras`. you should see this output :`Using TensorFlow backend.`

Best Regards

Comment: Sometimes `pip3` does not work correctly in system command line interface, so try to use this code in the jupyter notebook : `!pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` and for keras `!pip install keras`. And try to run mentioned code.